# Android Studio, populating listView from innerclass

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

Here is my code, when i use

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

array.add("kk");
array.add("bb");

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);

listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This will work fine in my onCreate method, but the problem is I can't us 'this' in an anonynmous class. replacing 'this' with getApplicationContext() does not work for some reason, either inside or outside the onCreate.

like this

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
```

Can anyone help me find the issue I have searched a lot but can not find an answer on this anywhere

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your anonymous class is inside your MainActivity. If this is the case you can simply do:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
```

When you use "this" inside your anonymous class, it refers to the anonymous inner class instance and not the instance of the outer class.

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the this-pointer via parameter in the constructor of the inner class and save it in a inner class field, like this ->

```
public class outerclass{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //.. other stuff
    innerclass ic = new innerclass(this);
    //.. other stuff
    }

    public class innerclass{
        private Context c;
        public innerclass(Context c){
            this.c = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use an adapter to add something into a list or an array, you need to alert the list, in this case array, that there was a change. After you call the add function, you need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Also, when declaring the adapter, declare it outside of onCreate() then assign your values inside onCreate()

`adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);`

See below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

    // List of array strings that will represent list items
    public static ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Array string will handle the information stored in the listview
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listItems);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
listItems.add(<value>);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Then if need be you also have access to:
`listItems.clear();` and `adapter.clear();`

Hope this helps!